# String to String array conversion with global variables

Tags: java, arrays

I have following problem with java.This method in Class should return *String* as is.

```
private String getAsString(Resource res) {

        return "We wish you good luck in this exam!\nWe hope you are well pre-\npared.";
    }
```

Then in Constructor this String shlud be converted into array of words

```
private int index;
private String string_arr[];

public TextFileIterator(Resource res) {
    this.index=0;
    if(res==null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    String text=this.getAsString(res);
    //text=text.replaceAll("-\n(?=[a-z])", "");
    text=text.replaceAll("\\n", "");
    text=text.replaceAll("!", " ");
    text=text.replaceAll("-", "");
    text=text.replaceAll(".", "");
    this.string_arr=text.split(" ");

}
```

Problem is that at the end I get array which is null... what is the problem. I attach the debugger screenshots.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please could explain me why does it happen?

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is line no 17-

```
text=text.replaceAll(".", "");
```

The above line is replacing all of the content with "", because in regex world "." means any character.

Try this instead-

```
text=text.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

Comment: Or `replace(".", "")`.

Comment: Yes that would also work. :). Because replaceAll() method expects first parameter as String regex while replace() method expects first parameter as CharSequence which need to be replaced.